# Is it possible to Autowire the JDO PersistenceManager or only the PersistenceManagerFactory?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-mvc, jdo

Is it possible to `Autowire` the JDO `PersistenceManager`?

In the example below, only the `PersistenceManagerFactory` is `Autowired`, while the `PersistenceManager` is obtained using a getter and utility method before each operation.

```
import org.springframework.orm.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryUtils;

@Service
public class MainServiceImpl implements MainService
{

    @Autowired
    private PersistenceManagerFactory pmf;

    private PersistenceManager pm;

    public void setPersistenceManager(PersistenceManager pm)
    {
        this.pm = pm;
    }

    public void setPmf(PersistenceManagerFactory pmf)
    {
        this.pmf = pmf;
    }

    public PersistenceManagerFactory getPmf()
    {
        return pmf;
    }

    public PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager()
    {
        return PersistenceManagerFactoryUtils.getPersistenceManager(pmf, true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look likely.

If you have a look at the [Spring JDO classes overview](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jdo/package-frame.html) you'll see the is no FactoryBean that returns a PersistenceManager.

Of course you can easily [implement a factory bean yourself](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) that has a dependency of type PersistenceManagerFactory and returns a PersistenceManager.

You may want to internally use the [TransactionAwarePersistenceManagerFactoryProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jdo/TransactionAwarePersistenceManagerFactoryProxy.html) if you always want to autowire the current thread-bound PersistenceManager (here's an excerpt from the JavaDoc)

> Proxy for a target JDO
>   PersistenceManagerFactory, returning
>   the current thread-bound
>   PersistenceManager (the Spring-managed
>   transactional PersistenceManager or
>   the single
>   OpenPersistenceManagerInView
>   PersistenceManager) on
>   getPersistenceManager(), if any.